# Delete method behavior in restheart

Tags: restheart

I'm running some tests with Restheart and noticed a strange behavior in the delete method.

When I try to delete a non-existent document, I' m received the collection relating to the document and the status http 200 as a result.

The correct would not return 404? Someone can explain me if this is the expected behavior for the restheart?

I'm using version 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I double checked and

```
DELETE /db/coll/notexistingid
```

Returns 404 as expected

Can you please provide your request?